# WTL, can't create toolbar

Tags: c++, user-interface, toolbar, wtl

I have an SDI-application. The frame class is:

```
class CMainFrame :
  public CFrameWindowImpl<CMainFrame>,    
  public CMessageFilter, 
  public CIdleHandler, 
  public CUpdateUI<CMainFrame>
{
  DECLARE_FRAME_WND_CLASS(NULL, IDR_MAINFRAME);
/*......*/
}
```

I have a menu and a toolbar in the resorce file, both have `IDR_MAINFRAME` ID's. The menu is created, but the toolbar not.

Creating the toolbar:

```
CreateSimpleToolBar();
CreateSimpleToolBar(IDR_MAINFRAME); // tried this also
UIAddToolBar(m_hWndToolBar);
UISetCheck(ID_VIEW_TOOLBAR, 1);
```

In the end of all i see no toolbar. `CreateSimpleToolBar` return non-zero.
How can i create the toolbar in WTL sdi-application? Thank you/

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the AppWizard you can add a default toolbar. You should check this code and find differences to your implementation. Maybe this helps: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3948/WTL-for-MFC-Programmers-Part-III-Toolbars-and-Stat

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i've already checked the link you posted. I've found the problem, it happens because there is wrong implementations of some of COM-interfaces methods in my class, but anyway, thank you for the response. It works as it should now.